# How do you draw a straight line with PolarPlot?

Tags: plotting

I can't figure how to draw a line with `PolarPlot`.

A vertical line through a is $r \cos(\theta) = a$, so

```
PolarPlot[a/Cos[theta], {theta, -Pi, Pi}]
```

works.

A horizontal line through b is $r \sin(\theta)=b$, so

```
PolarPlot[b/Sin[theta], {theta, -6, 6}]
```

works. (Using `{theta, -Pi, Pi}` doesn't work because of dividing by $\sin(0)=0$ I guess.)

How do I draw a radial line with $\theta = \pi/3$? Should be a line with slope 
$\tan(\pi/3)$. Can it be done with `PolarPlot`? I guess not since you have to give a function of $r$.

Comment: Related question: "how do I draw the line $x=1$ using only `Plot[]`?"

Comment: You can't draw this exactly but you can define a tangent arc of arbitrarily large radius which passes through the origin at the angle you want. Try creating a circle with variable radius which you can get to cut through `(0,0)` and then increase the radius until it looks like you want it to.

Comment: Can't you just use Epilog for this goal?

Comment: Mathematica is madness. On paper I write theta = pi/4 (or whatever angle) to get an expression of a line in polar coordinates. But Mathematica needs 140 characters of code???

Comment: Just add the `Epilog->{Line@{{x0,y0},{x1,y1}}` at the end of `PolarPlot` options list

Answer (score 6):

My friend, what you ask for is madness. Assuming you're completely aware of just doing this, or similar:

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[{4/Cos[theta], 4/Sin[theta]}, {theta, -6, 6}],
 Graphics[Rotate[Line[500 {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], Pi/3]]]
```

[image]

Here's the most obvious brute-force mickey mouse approach:

```
PolarPlot[{4/Cos[theta], 4/Sin[theta], Evaluate[
   If[Pi/3 < theta < Pi/3 + 4/(2 Pi Abs[#]), #] & /@
    Range[-30, 30, .717]
   ]}, {theta, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> 40, PlotPoints -> 400,
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.01]}, {Thickness[.01]}, Thickness[.01]}]
```

[image]

Exchanging some accuracy for performance:

```
PolarPlot[{4/Cos[theta], 4/Sin[theta],
  If[Pi/3 < theta < Pi/3 + .03, Range[-30, 30, .717]]
  }, {theta, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> 40, PlotPoints -> 400,
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Thickness[.01], Thickness[.01]}]
```

[image]

I mention these to show how arbitrary your functions in `Plot`s can be.

Here's one implementation of @Jonathan's idea:

```
PolarPlot[{4/Cos[theta], 4/Sin[theta], .2/(theta - Pi/3)},
 {theta, -2.1 Pi, 2.1 Pi}, PlotRange -> 40]
```

[image]

Another, flakier version:

```
PolarPlot[{4/Cos[theta], 4/Sin[theta], 10000 (theta - Pi/3)},
 {theta, -2.1 Pi, 2.1 Pi}, PlotRange -> 40]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the option [`PolarGridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarGridLines) to draw radial lines. For example:

```
PolarPlot[Cos[3 θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, PolarGridLines->{{π/3},{}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a straight line to a `PolarPlot`. To convert `PolarPlot[r[θ],{θ,a,b}]` to `ParametricPlot` use `Parametric[r[θ]*Cos[θ],r[θ]*Sin[θ]`, then add your line.

#### Method 1: Just use parametric plot instead. Line is `θ - Pi/3`.

```
scalingFact = 5;
pPa = ParametricPlot[
  {{Sin[3 t] Cos[t], Sin[3 t] Sin[t]}, {Cos[Pi/3]*t, Sin[Pi/3]*t}/scalingFact}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Parametric", ImageSize -> Tiny
]
```

#### Method 2: `PolarPlot` then `ParametricPlot` with line and `Show` both.

```
pPo = PolarPlot[{Red, Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> 10, 
 PlotLabel -> "Polar", ImageSize -> Tiny];

pPa = ParametricPlot[{Cos[Pi/3]*t, Sin[Pi/3]*t}/scalingFact, {t, 0, Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> Tiny];

Show[pPo, pPa, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Green}}]
```

Comment: my apologies obviously I am having trouble with this unusual editor. Could someone point me to some directions or a tutorial on how to input comments and code into this site properly. Thankyou

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

For lines that do not pass through the origin you can use the first argument of `PolarPlot` as follows:

```
PolarPlot[{4/Sin[theta], 4/Cos[theta], 10/(Sin[theta] + Cos[theta]), 
  10/(Sin[theta] - Cos[theta]), 20/(Sin[theta] + 3 Cos[theta])}, {theta, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

To add lines that pass through the origin you can use `Epilog` as suggested by Rom38 in a comment or `PolarGridLines` as in Carl's answer.